# Lasso selectables disables CSS :hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have a group of jquery ui selectable things inside a div which expands to full size upon the hover event.  The desired effect is that people can select/multi-select/lasso as many of the select-able objects as they would like.  When they are done selecting, and the mouse goes to another part of the page, the div returns to its minimized size.

Basically I have it working, but when I lasso-select multiple objects, it seems that the `:hover` state is canceled or disabled.  This leads to the div pre-maturely returning to its original size, and therefore destroying the user experience.

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6RX/2/

The div in question contains the blue "All Customers".  If you try lasso-selecting multiple objects you should see the problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when mouse is held down the element goes out of `:hover` and into the `:active` state [w3schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). Fortunately, you can apply a CSS class to both states without interupting the user

try this
http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6RX/3/

```
 #customer_picker:hover, #customer_picker:active {

    ...

    height: 300px;
 }
```